# <select...> DropDownList has no item to select on postback or validation fails

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I got two DropDownList on my view 'State' and 'District'. I used following code to populate the 'State' DDL.

Controller:-

```
var districts = (from r in db.Districts
                     select new { r.DistrictName });
ViewBag.DistrictName = new SelectList(districts, "DistrictName", "DistrictName");
```

View:-

```
@Html.DropDownList("State", ViewBag.StateName as SelectList, "Select a State")
```

Now, whenever one picks the State a json call populates 'District' DDL.

Controller:-

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult DistrictList(string Id)
{
    var districts = (from d in db.Districts
                        where d.State.StateName == Id
                        select new { d.DistrictName });
    return Json(new SelectList(districts, "DistrictName", "DistrictName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View:-

```
<select id="District"  name="District"></select>
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(function () {
        $('#State').change(function () {
            $.getJSON('/Application/DistrictList/' + $('#State').val(), function (data) {
                var items = '<option>Select a District</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, districts) {
                    items += "<option value='" + districts.Text + "'>" + districts.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#District').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And it works fine but the problem is, whenever any validation fails, 'District' DDL loosing its data. Again I need to make a new selection in 'State' and then 'District' got data from Json resutl. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your first option a dummy value, then check for it on the back-end:

```
var items = '<option value="-1">Select a District</option>';
```